# GitLab におけるプロジェクトのFork

Tags: git, gitlab

GitLab で、GitHub のようにプロジェクトをForkする方法はあるのでしょうか。

プロジェクトの親子関係を明確にして、
複数の派生したファイルを管理したいと考えています。

現在はブランチを分けて管理していますが、
複数のブランチを頻繁に行き来しなければならず、
非常に不便です。
また、それぞれを同時に動作させることもできません。

かといって、下記URLの方法でブランチから新たなレポジトリを作ると、
プロジェクトの親子関係を記録することができません。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527999/how-do-i-create-a-new-github-repo-from-a-branch-in-an-existing-repo

Comment: ver7.1.1というだいぶ古いものを使っていますが、`go to fork`ボタンからフォークできます。プロジェクトのトップページにありませんか？（お使いのバージョンも質問内に記述されることをお勧めします)

Comment: ver.7.6.2を使用していますが、'go to fork'ボタンが見当たりません。GitlabのChangelog(https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/CHANGELOG)でも、これを削除したとは書いてないので、不思議に思っています。。。

Comment: とすると、ユーザの権限周りの問題かもしれませんね。。詳しくないので他の方が回答されるのを待ちましょう。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

別ユーザでないと fork 出来ないようなので、それじゃないでしょうか？

一応、7.6.2 ([sameersbn/docker-gitlab](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab)) にて、fork するリンクのところと、管理画面で forks の数が見れるところの画像を貼っておきます。
これらが表示されてないとなると、なんか別の問題かもしれません。。

- 別ユーザ(ohga)が root/test を表示させて fork するところ。
  [image: forkするところ]
- Administrator の管理画面で forks を確認するところ。
  [image: 管理画面]